# Winforms Treeview text being cutoff

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I'm using a treeview inside my informs application.  When I load up nodes with a lot of text, the text gets chopped at 12 characters.  How do I keep this from happening?

Font being used:
Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt, style=Bold

I have tried using plain fonts with no luck.

Here is my code (I've overridden the treenode with another class):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Repetrel
{
    public class ActionObjectTreeNode: TreeNode
    {
    public string fileName = null;

    private ActionObject actionObject = new ActionObject();

    public string Text {
        get { return base.Text; }
        set {
            if (value.Equals(base.Text) == false && base.Text!="")
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("error detected");
            }
            base.Text = value;
        }
    }

    public ActionObject ACTIONOBJECT
    {
        get
        {
            return actionObject;
        }

        set
        {
            actionObject = value;
            if (value == null && TREENODETYPE != TreeNodeType.Project) {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("null assigned to actionobject");
            }
        }
    }
    public TreeNodeType TREENODETYPE { get; set; }
    public TreeNodeType LOCKEDNODETYPE { get; set; }
    public DrillActionGroup ACTIONPROPERTIES { get; set; }

    public ActionObjectTreeNode()
    {

    }

    public ActionObjectTreeNode(string text)
    {
        this.Text = text;
    }

    public ActionObjectTreeNode(ActionObject actionObject)
    {
        if (actionObject != null)
        {
            this.Text = actionObject.TEXT;
            this.ACTIONOBJECT = actionObject;
        }
    }


    public bool guidMatch(string _guid)
    {
        return ACTIONOBJECT.getGuid().Equals(_guid);       
    }

}
```

}

Comment: It's best to show the code that reproduces the problem for us.

Comment: The code doesn't reproduce the problem.  Are you overriding anything else?  You should be seeing a warning about using the "new" keyword in your override Text property.

Comment: @LarsTech - full code up now.  I'm not using the new keyword.

Comment: `this.Text = actionObject.TEXT;` ?  I would put a debugger on that line, see  what that value is.

Comment: @LarsTech - that code isn't being called.  I set the string directly via 'Text', which is overridden.

Comment: @LarsTech - Apparently I was cropping the text inside the treeview itself. Problem solved. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was cropping the text inside the treeview itself.  Problem solved.  Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Facing similar issue. What do you mean by cropping the text and how to disable it?

Comment: @Zaynmalik Its been a while. I'll let you know if my memory returns.

Answer (score 5):

Set the *font size property value* of the treeview higher than the *font size you set programmatically.*

[image: (image) Microsoft Help]

[image: (image) The Font property value of the treeview]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treenode.nodefont?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: If you include Images, the mark up includes an exlaimation mark. If you remove it, the mark up will only render a link.

Answer (score 2):

The text of a node may be truncated when you programmatically set the Font property of the node to the Bold value.

You need add an empty string to the text after you programmatically set the Font property of the node to the Bold value.

eg:

```
treeView1.Nodes[0].NodeFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12pt, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
treeView1.Nodes[0].Text += string.Empty;
```

Comment: I've tried plain text as well.  I'm getting the same results.